# Modify video frames but keep their timestamp in python skvideo ffmpeg

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, frame, video-processing

I have .ts videos with variable frame rate and I would like to modify the frames of the videos and keep the timestamps belonging to the frames. I am using python and experiencing with ffmpeg, but I am open to any solution.

The output of

> $ffmpeg -i myvideo.ts -hide_banner

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'myvideo.ts':
  Duration: 00:02:37.84, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 13799 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 3840x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
import skvideo.io

outpudict = {"-map": "0",
             "-vcodec": "libx264",
             "-pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
             "-f": "mpegts"
             }

videogen = skvideo.io.vreader(args.input_video)
writer = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter(filename + file_extension, outputdict=outpudict)
for i, frame in enumerate(videogen):
    # modify the frame
    writer.writeFrame(frame)

writer.close()
```

But so far I am not able to keep the pts and dts parameters of the frames only the format and encoding.

**Note:** I have tried to use skvideo.io.FFmpegReader or pass the outputdict parameter also to vreader but the script crashed because of [this bug](https://github.com/scikit-video/scikit-video/issues/60).

**Note2:** I am checking the pts of the frames with

> $ffprobe -hide_banner -show_entries packet=pts,dts myvideo.ts

Thank you for reading through my question, any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Depending on what kind of editing you're interested in, you may take a look at `opencv`. It gets frames as bitmaps aka `numpy` arrays and can use `ffmpeg` as backend. The primary use case for this is extracting information from each frame like objects and text.

Comment: yes, I've tried opencv also, but I could not find a way to save timestamp info with opencv neither. I was able to go further with skvideo. Do you know how could I do that with opencv?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527882/ffmpeg-copyts-to-preserve-timestamp may be useful. also vsync vfr https://superuser.com/questions/908295/ffmpeg-libx264-how-to-specify-a-variable-frame-rate-but-with-a-maximum

Comment: Thanks, the vsync option was new to me, I tried to insert "-vsync": "0" into my parameters but it did not solve my problem :(